# C# : Application doesn't access database in client pc

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

I have installed sql server in client pc but the app doesn't access database.

this is my connection string :

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

please, is there other apps must be installed in client pc (e.g., SSMS)?

Comment: Have you tried to open your app as admin ?

Comment: can you access the database using sql server?

Comment: Is the application deployed in IIS ? If yes, can you tell me what is your Application Pool Identity for this app ?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: i have create the database in vs itself
and only change the connection string and installed sql server express in client pc .. what shall i do ?

Comment: yes, i get exceptions but in app i handle it.

Comment: i realize that app can't access the database !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sql server express install with it the localDb.

i have install SSMS and it solve the issue !

now i realize that client pc must install 2 Apps :

1- Sql Server Epress

2- Sql Server Management Studio

thanks every one,

Answer (score 1):

Make that Integrated Security=False in connection string as below

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myDB.mdf;Integrated Security=False;User Instance=True"
```

This might be helpful for you